# joomla - List products under category

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

i will list product to the specified category but it dosnt work. I think its a Error anywhere in sql query...

```
$query = "
            SELECT 
                cat.`name_".$language."` AS catname,
                cat.category_id AS category_id, 
                prod.`name_".$language."` AS prodname,
                prod.product_id AS product_id
            FROM 
                `#__jshopping_products` AS prod
            INNER JOIN 
                `#__jshopping_products_to_categories` AS pr_cat 
            ON 
                pr_cat.product_id = prod.product_id
            LEFT JOIN 
                `#__jshopping_categories` AS cat 
            ON 
                pr_cat.category_id = cat.category_id
            WHERE 
                prod.product_publish = '1'
            AND 
                cat.category_publish='1'
            AND 
                pr_cat.product_id = prod.product_id
            ";
$db->setQuery($query);
$row = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ($row as $value) {
  print_r("Katname: ".$value->catname."<br>Produkte zur Kategorie: ".$value->prodname."<br><br>");
}
```

sql tables

```
categories
category_id, name
products
product_id, name
products_to_categories
category_id, product_id
```

print_r show this:

```
Katname: Wandbilder
Produkte: Acryl Schild
Katname: Dekoration
Produkte: Pappdisplay
Katname: Wandbilder
Produkte: Pappdisplay
Katname: Dekoration
Produkte: Foto-Tischläufer & Tischdecke
...​
```

I will print eg.

```
Katname: Wandbilder Produkte: Acryl Schild, Pappdisplay, ...
Katname: Dekoration Produkte: Pappdisplay, Foto-Tischläufer & Tischdecke​, ...
....
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Why don't you do at least the 1st step of debugging and provide us with an actual error message, so we do not have analyse the sql statement line by line?

Answer (score 0):

`$query = "
            SELECT 
                cat.name_".$language." AS catname,
                cat.category_id AS category_id
            FROM 
                #__jshopping_categories AS cat`

```
        WHERE
            cat.category_publish='1'

        ";
$db->setQuery($query);
$row = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($row as $value) {

    print_r("<br><br>Katname: ".$value->catname."<br><br>\n");

$query = "
        SELECT 
            prod.`name_".$language."` AS prodname,
            prod.product_id AS product_id
        FROM 
            `#__jshopping_products` AS prod
        LEFT JOIN 
            `#__jshopping_products_to_categories` AS pr_cat 
        ON 
            pr_cat.product_id = prod.product_id
        WHERE
            prod.product_publish='1'
        AND
            pr_cat.category_id = ".$value->category_id."


        ";
$db->setQuery($query);
$row = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($row as $value) {

    print_r("Produkte: ".$value->prodname."<br>\n");
}
```

}